# Why am I not getting Output? Can anyone help me?

Tags: java

I have declared a variable of type long and I want to print the statements if the given variable lies between the range specified -

```
class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long n = 3454546L;

        if (-2147483648L<=n && n>=2147483647L) {
            System.out.println("* int");
            System.out.println("* long");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code.

Comment: It doesn't print anything because 3454546 is not larger than 2147483647.

Comment: the condition can never be true.

Comment: @Saketh just as information, you can use the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of entering the numbers directly

Comment: Please have a look at [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 3):

Because your logic is is `n >= -2147483648L` true and `n >= 2147483647L` false so overall false?
Think you wanted

```
-2147483648L<= n && n<=2147483647L
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second part being `n>=2147483647L` is not matching, thus you have false and will not go into the statements, i guess it should be `n<=2147483647L`?